# NotFoundError on OpKernel when using tf.nn.embedding_lookup in tensorflow eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use GPU acceleration in eager mode in tensorflow 1.7rc1, however I keep encountering NotFoundError in various tf functions. The following is my simple test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import math
import numpy as np

tfe.enable_eager_execution()

num_sampled=64
vocabulary_size = 512
embedding_size = 128

train_dataset = tf.constant(np.array([1,3,4,5,4]))
train_labels = tf.constant(tf.transpose(np.array([[1,2,1,2,0]])))

embeddings = tfe.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
softmax_weights = tfe.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                     stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
softmax_biases = tfe.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #the ID can be a list of words
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
    print(loss)
```

And I received the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f6ef06e0fbcf> in <module>()
     21     embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #the ID can be a list of words
     22     loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
---> 23                                    labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
     24     print(loss)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py in sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1340       partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
   1341       name=name,
-> 1342       seed=seed)
   1343   sampled_losses = nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
   1344       labels=labels, logits=logits)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py in _compute_sampled_logits(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, subtract_log_q, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1039           unique=True,
   1040           range_max=num_classes,
-> 1041           seed=seed)
   1042     # NOTE: pylint cannot tell that 'sampled_values' is a sequence
   1043     # pylint: disable=unpacking-non-sequence

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\candidate_sampling_ops.py in log_uniform_candidate_sampler(true_classes, num_true, num_sampled, unique, range_max, seed, name)
    139   return gen_candidate_sampling_ops.log_uniform_candidate_sampler(
    140       true_classes, num_true, num_sampled, unique, range_max, seed=seed1,
--> 141       seed2=seed2, name=name)
    142 
    143 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_candidate_sampling_ops.py in log_uniform_candidate_sampler(true_classes, num_true, num_sampled, unique, range_max, seed, seed2, name)
    755       else:
    756         message = e.message
--> 757       _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
    758 
    759 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

NotFoundError: No registered 'LogUniformCandidateSampler' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node LogUniformCandidateSampler = LogUniformCandidateSampler[num_sampled=64, num_true=1, range_max=512, seed=0, seed2=0, unique=true](dummy_input)
    .  Registered:  device='CPU'
 [Op:LogUniformCandidateSampler]
```

Can someone please help? The code seems to run properly when I use `tf.device('\cpu:0')`. I am using tensorflow 1.7rc1 on Windows 10. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you're explicitly asking for the loss computation to execute on GPU (by placing the call to `tf.nn. sampled_softmax_loss` in the `with tf.device("/gpu:0")` block), but it can't since the underlying operation is not implemented for GPU. 
This error isn't specific to eager execution, you'd get the same error with graph execution as well (e.g., using `with tf.Session() as sess: print(sess.run(loss))`)

If you structure the code to be less prescriptive about where individual operations should execute, it will give TensorFlow the flexibility to run the operation where it can. For example, move the loss computation outside the `with tf.device` block:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #the ID can be a list of words
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
                              labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
print(loss)
```

A side note: In TensorFlow 1.7, eager execution does not use a GPU without an explicit `with tf.device("/gpu:0")`. However, with the [next version of TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.8.0-rc0) a GPU will be used if possible even when there is no explicit device specification (more details in [tensorflow/tensorflow#14133](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14133)). So, if you're able, I'd suggest using 1.8.0-rc0 instead of 1.7.0-rc1 and then you can do away with the `with tf.device("/gpu:0")` completely.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!